# How do i get these marked values?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the below-mentioned values and want them to be in the spinner?

Below is the data tree from Firebase database and the values that I want to fetch or read are commented below:

```
"Courses Details" : {
    "Bs-BBA" : {                 /// These are the value that i am trying to read and fetch
      "-MVuhKkfxjHkZmTfsITM" : {
        "Economics" : {
          "courseName" : "Economics",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Tuesday",
          "endingTime" : "1:30Pm",
          "programName" : "Bs-BBA",
          "startingTime" : "12:00Pm"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bscs" : {                /// These are the value that i am trying to read and fetch
      "-MVWl1uq9fA4AlYRfMIv" : {
        "Data structure" : {
          "courseName" : "Data structure",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Monday",
          "endingTime" : "9:30AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVY9hGxrp8Lz4JTOefy" : {
        "OOP" : {
          "courseName" : "OOP",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      },
      "-MVYHM0c7cMLersoUl2i" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bscs",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      }
    },
    "Bsse" : {         /// These are the value that i am trying to read and fetch
      "-MVYHB3X_d4UozbBUDa3" : {
        "Marketing Fundamental" : {
          "courseName" : "Marketing Fundamental",
          "courseSection" : "A",
          "dayOfCourse" : "Thursday",
          "endingTime" : "9:00AM",
          "programName" : "Bsse",
          "startingTime" : "8:00AM"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

And this is the code that i wrote this far for reading or fetching th above mentioned values:

```
public void getDataIntoSpinnerForProgramNameFromFirebase()
        {
    
            dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses Details");
    
            listener = dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
    
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
                {
    
                    spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.clear();
    
                    for( DataSnapshot programAndDepartmentName:snapshot.getChildren() )
                    {
    
                        if( programAndDepartmentName.child("programNameAndDepartmentName").exists() )
                        {
                            spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.add(programAndDepartmentName.child("programNameAndDepartmentName").toString());
    
                        }
                    }
    
                    /*for( DataSnapshot departments:snapshot.getChildren() )
                    {
    
                        for( DataSnapshot programNames:departments.getChildren() )
                        {
    
                            if (programNames.child("Program Name").exists())
                            {
    
                                spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.add(programNames.child("Program Name").getValue().toString());
    
                            }
    
                        }
    
                    }*/
                    spinnerForProgramNameArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

How can I fetch or read the above-mentioned values from the Firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "Courses Details" is a direct child of your Firebase Realtime Database root reference, to get the highlighted values, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference coursesDetailsRef = rootRef.child("Courses Details");
coursesDetailsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getkey();
                spinnerForProgramNameArrayList.add(key);
                Log.d("TAG", key);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat of the above code will be:

```
Bs-BBA
Bs-BBA
Base
```

Ane the addition of the above values in the "spinnerForProgramNameArrayList".

P.S. As we are using **get()**, please be sure to have at least **19.6.0** version of Firebase Realtime Database dependency.